# onMouseEnter doesn't work when mouse go fast through the element

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I know that this question peoples asked many times but I've not found any answer which give me opportunity to solve this issue

```
<Zoom in timeout={500}>
    <div
        onMouseEnter={() => {
            console.log('enter')
        }}
        onMouseLeave={this.handlePopoverClose}
        className={classes.paperInside}>
            {providers.map((entity, index) => {
                return (<GameBox
                    key={index + 'box'}
                        element={entity}
                        isDivider={index === 3 && index !== 0}
                />)
            })}
        <Count
            count={count}
            to={`/games/${type}`}
            sectionName={element.name}
             />
    </div>
</Zoom>
```

Lets imagine that I have some `div` element , when I try go with my mouse through this element fast it doesn't work . I know that if you not enter element `onMouseLeave` will not work. But I really need that `onMouseLeave` triggers each time when i enter end then leave it . Pls if my question isn't clear enough let me know

Comment: Please verify my answer if you find it helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your scenario works for me as expected. I don't know what problem you are really facing.

You can have a look at my example

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head><title>onmouse event demo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>onmouse event demo</h3>
    <p>Fires when the mouse pointer enters and leave the element.</p>
    <div id="mouse_event" style="width:300px;height:100px;border:1px solid;" onMouseEnter="javascript:document.getElementById('mouse_event').innerHTML = 'enter event has been triggered' " onMouseLeave="javascript:document.getElementById('mouse_event').innerHTML = 'leave event has been triggered' ">Demo text</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rinold/3ghnefw9/18/)